# Split 5.1/7.1 audio into multiple outputs

Tags: audio, sound-card, surround-sound, audio-output

I'm getting a new computer in my home studio I would like to have multiple stereo outputs so I can properly DJ and do things like cue up a track with headphones or do separate analog processing live along with my digital stuff.

In my search for sound cards I found a lot of surround sound ones for real cheap and I was wondering if I could use the outputs on those as normal stereo outputs. I will have Windows 10 installed and my motherboard will have internal sound capabilities out of the box, if that information helps at all.

Any help is appreciated - Otto

Comment: This was true of many sound cards in the past and is probably unlikely to have changed (though, regarding physical jacks, you would likely be limited to just one Stereo Output).